# Are nullable reference types just for static analysis?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about what nullable reference types are needed for. As I understand it, they are needed only for static analysis of the code for the possibility of null. Can you tell me if I'm right?

Comment: Well, yes. What else could they be used for?

Comment: Hi @EtiennedeMartel thare are a lot of thing under the hood on Nullable reference type. feel free to take a look at the response. Thanks!

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel They can also be used at runtime with reflection over the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [MS official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) about this topic. But basically these Nullable reference types includes three major features which avoid null reference exception and the possibility to explicitly tell that a reference type is nullable.

> 1. Improved static flow analysis that determines if a variable may be
>    null before dereferencing it.

For instance the warning Non-nullable property 'name' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor can be easily addressed in two ways(Constructor chaining and nullable attributes)

```
  [MemberNotNull(nameof(Major))]
    private void SetMajor(string? major = default)
    {
        Major = major ?? "Undeclared";
    }
```

> 2. Attributes that annotate APIs so that the flow analysis determines
>    null-state.

For instance:

```
public void PrintMessage(string message)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {message}");
    }
}
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace([NotNullWhen(false)] string message);
```

> 3. Variable annotations that developers use to explicitly declare the
>    intended null-state for a variable.

For instance:

```
string? name;

name!.Length;
```

I would also recomment to take a look at Generics (T?) and Nullable contexts